# Boundedness for resolvents of perturbed operators

Tags: operator-theory, differential-operators

( might not be a research-level question... if it violates any term of this website I will delete it ASAP )

I'm wondering if there is any way to show the boundedness/unboundedness of operators like $(\partial_x + f )^{-1}$ or $(H\partial_x +f)^{-1}$, such as in $L^2 (\mathbb{R})$. (Here $H$ is the Hilbert transform, $f$ is a bounded smooth function, but possibly we need more assumptions on that...? ) Could anyone give me a clue or tell me if there is any literature to follow?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Operators involving derivatives are, as a rule, never bounded.

Comment: Oh sorry I just found out that I made a typo in the question...It should be the inverses of those operators. Thanks anyway!

Comment: The operator $(-i\partial_x + 3)^{-1}$ is not bounded, where $3$ could also be any real number, though it becomes bounded when $3$ is replaced by any non-real complex number. You can check this explicitly if you write its fundamental solution as an integral operator with kernel $G(x,x')$, where $(-i\partial_x +3) G(x,x') = \delta(x-x')$. The same goes for your differential operators, if you can get some information about their fundamental solutions (look up the "variation of constants" formula, if you don't know it already).

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that same thing happens for operators like $(\partial_x +1 )^{-1}$ ? ( I can assume $f$ is real-valued in this question actually)

Comment: Now (= your comment) you're asking if $-1$ is outside the spectrum of $d/dx$, which is true because this operator (on a suitable domain) has purely imaginary spectrum.

Comment: Why don't you just solve the first order ODE as usual (integrating factors, etc.). That will give you a fairly explicit kernel for the inverse and it may happen that one of the standard (un)boundedness tests will apply to your particular case.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thanks! But how can one deal with the operator with the Hilbert transform and a general function $f$ ?

Comment: @fedja Thanks! It's just that I still need to deal with the operator with the Hilbert transform together with the function $f$

Comment: OK, that may be trickier. Let me think...

Comment: @Ever_99, if your $H$ denotes the Hilbert transform, rather than a constant or a function of $x$, you should state that explicitly. That information significantly changes part of your question.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine My apologize for that - just edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: The whole set-up really seems unnatural to me as both operators are unbounded for $f=0$, so they won't be bounded for small $f$ (for example, a relatively compact perturbation). What kind of class of functions $f$ did you have in mind?

Comment: On the other hand, $id/dx$ and $Hd/dx$ (are self-adjoint on suitable domains and) have spectrum $\mathbb R$ and $[0,\infty)$, respectively (maybe I'm off by a sign here). This means that if $f=c + g$, $c$ outside the spectrum and $g$ small in a suitable sense, then your resolvent will be bounded.